# How do I get a 'copy of a cheque'?

Tags: united-kingdom, banking, bonds, check, personal-check

Sorry if this is a stupid question, but how do I get a copy of a cheque?

I'm going through the process of encashment of some bonds which I received as inheritance, to do this I need to send over a copy of a cheque to prove my bank details.

Now, I haven't seen a real cheque book since I was a child, I've never had one before, and last I heard they were being phased out here (UK). I'm sure that I can order one from my bank, but what do I need to do with that to make a copy? Do I need to make a payment with a cheque and get a photocopy of it? Who would accept a cheque? Can I do it remotely? These are covid times after all.

Comment: Um. This sounds very fishy and weird. Are you 100% sure that this "inheritance" is legitimate? Yes, your sort code and account number are written on the bottom of a cheque, but for any legitimate reason when I have ever needed to supply them I have been able to just type them in myself rather than providing a copy of a cheque or bank statement.

Comment: @Vicky a few years ago, I had to photograph a (voided, of course) blank check in order to set up Direct Deposit.  My son didn't, two years ago.

Comment: This is very archaic.  Have you asked the *whoever is cashing the bonds*?

Comment: To Vicky’s point, same here. Some bills I pay with a direct debit, property tax for instance, just need me to provide my bank routine number and account number. Haven’t seen the voided check requested in a long time. Her caution is well placed.

Comment: Who exactly is asking for this information and how did they word that request?

Comment: Yep, I appreciate this all sounds *super* sketchy. It's all being managed by a family member who is the trustee and set up the bonds in the first place, with a seemingly legit wealth management service based in London. I've ordered a cheque book and hopefully a scan of one will be enough